# Find the height $h$ of a circular segment based on the Radius $R$ and length $c$

Tags: geometry

I have found the formula for calculating the R of a circle, based on a circular segment, which is:

$$ R=\frac{h}2+\frac{c^2} {8h}$$

where $R$ is radius, $c$ is the length of the segment, and $h$ is the height of the segment.

What I want to do is solve this equation for $h$. e.g. `h=[...]`.

I have been trying, but for me it boils down to the fact that I don't know how to solve an equation with the form $a+b=a*d$ for $a$.

Comment: its a quadratic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply throughout by $h$. Then this is a quadratic, use the standard formula to solve for $h$.

After multiplying with $h$
$$ Rh = \frac{h^2} 2 + \frac{c^2} 8 $$

Rearranging it gives

$$ \frac12 h^2 + (-R)h + \frac{c^2} 8 = 0 $$

Using the quadratic formula, you can solve for $h$

$$ h = \frac{-(-R)± \sqrt{(-R)^2-4\frac12\frac{c^2} 8}} {2 \cdot \frac12} $$

Which can be simplified as

$$ h = R± \sqrt{R^2-\frac{c^2} 4} $$

Comment: I'll accept this answer if you could write out the steps. I personally can't see how the formula after you multiply by h is a quadratic.

Comment: @sigsve $Rh = {h^2 \over 2} + {c^2 \over 8}$. Can you see now?

Comment: Yes. Don't know why I didn't see it before..